# Problems with Retrieving Data From Firebase In Swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I've set up some data objects in Firebase and I'm trying to retrieve them in Wwift and display them in a table view but I'm unable to get any result.

**What i've tried?**

```
var crystalsList = [Crystal]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(crystalsList.count)
    crystalRef = Database.database().reference().child("crystalList")

    crystalRef?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.crystalsList.removeAll()

            for myCrystal in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                let crystalObject = myCrystal.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                let name = crystalObject?["name"]
                let colors = crystalObject?["colors"]
                let mainColor = crystalObject?["mainColor"]
                let region = crystalObject?["region"]
                let rarity = crystalObject?["rarity"]
                let additionalInfo = crystalObject?["additionalInfo"]
                let primaryUse = crystalObject?["primaryUse"]
                let isNew = crystalObject?["isNew"]

                let theCrystal = Crystal(name: (name as! String?)!, rarity: (rarity as! String?)!, region: (region as! String?)!, color: (colors as! String?)!, mainColor: (mainColor as! String?)!, isNewListing: (isNew as! Bool), additionalInfo: (additionalInfo as! String?)!, primaryUse: (primaryUse as! String?)!)

                self.crystalsList.append(theCrystal)
            }

            self.crystalTable.reloadData()
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: This code is not enough to troubleshoot. Show the JSON for (the relevant part of) your database (as text, no screenshots).Get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also run the code in a debugger and set breakpoints on crucial lines. Does it get into your callback block? Finally: do you have permission to read the data:  https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/24788/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-ios#t=201707020102526875005

Comment: Thank you for the response, i went over the article you provided and it turns out that i didn't have permission to read the data so i went ahead and fixed that and i'm now able to print the data.

Comment: Good to hear that you got it sorted based on that link. I'm not sure how to resolve this question, so voted to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to frank, i was able to resolve this issue by going into firebase and allowing the permission to read the data.